# construction of a measure from a cumulative distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was trying to solve an exercise in my book (Cinlar - Probability and Stochastics - II.1.20) but I have some problems understanding what it asks of me. The exercise asks for the following.

---

Ex. Let $c:\mathbb R\to [0,1]$ a cumulative distribution function, that is increasing and right continuous. Let $q:(0,1)\to \mathbb R$ the corresponding quantile function (i.e. $q$ is the generalized inverse of $c$; $q(u)=inf \{t|c(t)>u\}$). Let $L$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$ and put $\mu=L \circ q^{-1}$.

(a) Show that $\mu$  is a measure on $\overline{ \mathbb R} $.

(b) Show tha $\mu$ is the distribution on $\overline{ \mathbb R} $ corresponding to the distribution funcion $c$. Thus, to every distribution $c$ on $\mathbb R$ there corresponds an unique probability measure $\mu $ on $\overline{ \mathbb R} $ and viceversa.

---

My doubts (only in the b point):

I didn't understand what the author means by "distribution on $\overline{ \mathbb R} $ corresponding to the distribution funcion $c$". 
In fact the only type of distribution defined in the book is the measure $\mu_X:\mathcal B_{\mathbb R}\to [0,1]$ relative to a random variable $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ (that is $\mu _X(A)=\mathbb P(X^{-1}(A))$). 
What does he mean?
That exists a random variable $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ such that $c_{X}=c$ ?

NB: by definition the author put  $c_{X}(y)=\mathbb P(X^{-1}]-\infty,y])$ for all $y \in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part (a) is a change fo variables. You have that $q$ is a map from the measure space $((0,1),\mathscr{B}(0,1)),L)$  to the measurable space $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B})$. You can convince yourself that the map
$\mu:\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow[0,1]$ given by
$\mu(B)=L(q^{-1}(B))$ is indeed a measure (in fact a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.

The second part requires you to convince yourself that
$$c(x)\geq t\quad\text{if and only if}\quad q(t)\leq x$$

So $\mu((-\infty,x])=L(\{t:q(t)\leq x\})=L(\{t:c(x)\geq t\})=c(x)$